# Show list of authors with latest post NOT older than a month

Tags: wp-query, php, list-authors

I found two bits of code. One gets me posts NOT older than a month the other bit gets me a list of authors and their custom fields, names, etc.

Can someone please help me integrate the two. One runs in the wordpress loop with a custom query and the other is a foreach (all stuff I don't know much of). How can I get the two to work together.

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php
        $display_admins = false;
        $order_by = 'display_name';
        $role = ''; // 'subscriber', 'contributor', 'editor', 'author' - leave blank for 'all'
        $hide_empty = false;

        if(!empty($display_admins)) {
            $blogusers = get_users('orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
        } else {
            $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
            $exclude = array();
            foreach($admins as $ad) {
                $exclude[] = $ad->ID;
            }
            $exclude = implode(',', $exclude);
            $blogusers = get_users('exclude='.$exclude.'&orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
        }
        $authors = array();
        foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
            $user = get_userdata($bloguser->ID);
            if(!empty($hide_empty)) {
                $numposts = count_user_posts($user->ID);
                if($numposts < 1) continue;
            }
            $authors[] = (array) $user;
        }
<?php
            foreach($authors as $author) {
                $display_name = $author['data']->display_name;
                $main_profile = get_the_author_meta('mainProfile', $author['data']->ID);
                $hover_profile = get_the_author_meta('hoverProfile', $author['data']->ID);
                $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($author['ID']);
        ?>

            <div class="da-author">

                <div class="original-image">
                    <img src="<?php echo $main_profile; ?>" alt="<?php echo $display_name; ?>">
                </div>

                <div class="hover-image">
                    <a href="<?php echo $author_profile_url; ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $hover_profile; ?>">
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>

        <?php}?>
```

Loop:

```
<?php
            $args =  array(
                'showposts' => 1,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'date_query' => array(
                    array(
                        'after' => array(
                            'year'  => date( "Y" ),
                            'month' => date( "m", strtotime( "-1 Months" ) ),
                            'day'   => date( "t", strtotime( "-1 Months" ) ),
                        ),
                        'inclusive' => true,
                    )
                )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
        ?>

            <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>

        <?php }} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query needs to include an argument to specify the author, and would need to be inside one of your "author" Loops. In fact, I see no need to Loop over your author data twice. Once should be fine.

```
$display_admins = false;
$order_by = 'display_name';
$role = ''; // 'subscriber', 'contributor', 'editor', 'author' - leave blank for 'all'
$hide_empty = false;

if(!empty($display_admins)) {
    $blogusers = get_users('orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
} else {
    $admins = get_users('role=administrator');
    $exclude = array();
    foreach($admins as $ad) {
        $exclude[] = $ad->ID;
    }
    $exclude = implode(',', $exclude);
    $blogusers = get_users('exclude='.$exclude.'&orderby='.$order_by.'&role='.$role);
}

foreach($blogusers as $author) {
  $args =  array(
    'author' => $author->ID, // here is your author ID
    'showposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'date_query' => array(
      array(
        'after' => array(
        'year'  => date( "Y" ),
        'month' => date( "m", strtotime( "-1 Months" ) ),
        'day'   => date( "t", strtotime( "-1 Months" ) ),
      ),
      'inclusive' => true,
      )
    )
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ($query->have_posts()) {

    $display_name = $author->data->display_name;
    $main_profile = get_the_author_meta('mainProfile', $author->ID);
    $hover_profile = get_the_author_meta('hoverProfile', $author->ID);
    $author_profile_url = get_author_posts_url($author->ID); ?>

    <div class="da-author">

      <div class="original-image">
          <img src="<?php echo $main_profile; ?>" alt="<?php echo $display_name; ?>">
      </div>

      <div class="hover-image">
          <a href="<?php echo $author_profile_url; ?>">
              <img src="<?php echo $hover_profile; ?>">
          </a>
      </div>

    </div><?php
    // a post Loop
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
      $query->the_post();
      the_title();
      // etc.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help s_ha_dum I appreciate it. For some reason though, only the one author gets displayed and not all of them. Also, the one post that is younger than a month displays as expected but I have to include that inside the "da-author" divs somehow so each author with a new post will have their post title showing.